# SRX FW - Show route - output reject

Tags: routing, juniper, srx

Running SRX firewall, and when running command show route, one of the outputs shows as reject
could you help in troubleshooting the reason for this

10.14.224.193/32   *[Local/0] 24w6d 22:05:53
                      Reject

Comment: You really need to include the device configuration.

Comment: which configuration required, if you could provide me with configuration line start statement, thus i could filter and share

Comment: The configuration of the firewall. You can obfuscate passwords and public addresses, but without the configuration, we are reduced to speculating and guessing, but that is off-topic here.

Comment: i have no issue, but the original configuration is 200K+ lines. that's why i asked to specify

Answer (score 2):

Most common reasons to reject route on local interface is:

- interface with assigned IP is down/disabled
- there is IP conflict and this IP is assigned in two places, could be even on unused interface etc.
- zone misconfiguration

Please supply full configuration so we can advise.

Comment: interface with assigned IP is down/disabled

i searched the full configuration, and nothing difference than other interfaces, so i guess its not

Comment: there is IP conflict and this IP is assigned in two places, could be even on unused interface etc.

full configuration searched, and no conflict at all but am doing now another search to double check

Comment: zone misconfiguration

as am comparing the zone configuration, to other zones nothing noticed as difference

Comment: Please supply full configuration so we can advise.

please let me know the exact configuration required, and will do so

Comment: Your interface is down.  Nothing to do with Zones, nothing to to with duplicate IPs

Comment: Interface is down?
is it from FW configuration side?
or neighbor device?

as the interface configuration, looks for me, as OK and UP, and here it is to check your side (maybe am wrong)
set interfaces reth4 unit 1549 vlan-id 1549  
set interfaces reth4 unit 1549 family inet address 10.14.224.193/26